# Axes' and titles' fonts and size seem deactivated after using ggplotly()

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly

I have this dataframe

```
gene_symbol<-c("DADA","SDAASD","SADDSD","SDADD","ASDAD","XCVXCVX","EQWESDA","DASDADS","SDASDASD","DADADASD","sdaadfd","DFSD","SADADDAD","SADDADADA","DADSADSASDWQ","SDADASDAD","ASD","DSADD")
panel<-c("growth","growth","growth","growth","big","big","big","small","small","dfgh","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","gh","DF","DF")
ASDDA<-c("normal","over","low","over","normal","over","low","over","normal","over","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF")
ASDDb<-c("normal","over","low","over","normal","over","low","over","normal","over","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF")
ASDDAf<-c("normal","over","low","over","normal","over","low","over","normal","over","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF")
ASDDAf1<-c("normal","over","low","over","normal","over","low","over","normal","over","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF")
ASDDAf2<-c("normal","over","low","over","normal","over","low","over","normal","over","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF")
ASDDAf3<-c("normal","over","low","over","normal","over","low","over","normal","over","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF")
ASDDAf4<-c("normal","over","low","over","normal","over","low","over","normal","over","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF")
ASDDAf5<-c("normal","over","low","over","normal","over","low","over","normal","over","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF")
ASDDA1<-c("normal","over","low","over","normal","over","low","over","normal","over","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF")
ASDDb1<-c("normal","over","low","over","normal","over","low","over","normal","over","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF")
ASDDAf1<-c("normal","over","low","over","normal","over","low","over","normal","over","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF")
ASDDAf11<-c("normal","over","low","over","normal","over","low","over","normal","over","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF")
ASDDAf21<-c("normal","over","low","over","normal","over","low","over","normal","over","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF")
ASDDAf31<-c("normal","over","low","over","normal","over","low","over","normal","over","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF")
ASDDAf41<-c("normal","over","low","over","normal","over","low","over","normal","over","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF")
ASDDAf51<-c("normal","over","low","over","normal","over","low","over","normal","over","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF")
Gene_states22 <- data.frame(gene_symbol, panel, ASDDA, ASDDb, ASDDAf, ASDDAf1, ASDDAf2, 
                            ASDDAf3, ASDDAf4, ASDDAf5, ASDDA1, ASDDb1, ASDDAf1, ASDDAf11,
                            ASDDAf21, ASDDAf31, ASDDAf41, ASDDAf51)
```

And I create those heatmaps withh gplot2

```
    library(plotly)
library(ggplot2); library(reshape2)
HG3<-split(Gene_states22[,1:15], Gene_states22$panel)
HG4 <- melt(HG3, id.vars= c("gene_symbol","panel"))
HG4<-HG4[,-5]
HG5<-split(HG4, HG4$panel)
pp <- ggplot(HG4, 
       aes(gene_symbol,variable)) + 
  geom_tile(aes(fill = value),
            colour = "grey50") + 
  facet_grid(~panel, scales = "free") +

  # it looks like you have more colours than values here.
  # I recommend using a named vector in this case, so that 
  # the same value always maps to the same colour.
  # e.g. values = c("DF" = "white", "low" = "red", ...)
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("white", "red", "blue", "black", "yellow", "green", "brown")) +

  labs(title = "Heatmap", x = "gene_symbol", y = "sample", fill = "value") +
  guides(fill = FALSE)+
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = NA),
        panel.spacing = unit(0, "lines"),
        strip.placement = "outside")
```

Then I convert them to plotly

```
ggplotly(pp,
         width = 1350, height = 600) %>%
  # note: specifying width / height in layout() has been deprecated
  # in recent versions of plotly. when I used it that way, I got
  # a warning to specify it within ggplotly() instead.
  layout(autosize = F,  yaxis = list(title = "sample",family = "Calibri", 
                                    size = 11),
         hoverlabel = list(bgcolor = "white",
                           font = list(family = "sans serif", size = 9, color = "black")))
```

The problem is that the font, size and boldness of my title and axes' title do not seem to be avtivated and to work properly. Also the title "Heatmap" should have been a little higher and not stuck in the graph.

Comment: `HG4` is missing.

Comment: Sorry I editted

Comment: and `csvdata3` is also not defined.

Comment: OK..try now plz.

Answer (score 1):

I think they are. You could remove the title and use annotation to place your legend in the right place. You can adjust the font size and location as you wish.

What about this?

```
ggplotly(pp, width = 1350, height = 598) %>%
    add_annotations(
        yref="paper", 
        xref="paper", 
        y=1.09, 
        x=0, 
        text="Heatmap", 
        showarrow=F, 
        font=list(size=18)
    ) %>% 
    layout(title=FALSE)
```

[image]